# Consuming F# from a C# project: Getting a "method Not Found"

Tags: f#, assembly-binding-redirect

I have a .NET class defined like so in an F# project:

```
type public StockAnalyzer() = 
    member public this.GetStockClose ticker = 
        try
            let stockInfo = YahooContext.Load("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + ticker)
            let mostRecent = stockInfo.Rows |> Seq.head
            (float)mostRecent.``Adj Close``
        with 
            | :?  System.Net.WebException -> -1.0
```

When I try and run this from a C# unit test project and an ASP.NET applciation, I am getting this:

> Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1

This class also has 1 other method that are using

```
message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

Is that causing the interop to fail on the async?  Even though I am not even calling that method?

Comment: Add binding redirect for FSharp.Core

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon what Fyodor Soikin said in his comment, this often happens as a result of mismatched versions of FSharp.Core between the unit test project and whatever you're trying to test.

You can create a binding redirect, which redirects the references to a different version of FSharp.Core.  You do this by creating an `App.config` file in your project, it should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

See: https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html#use-binding-redirects-for-applications

That page is obviously also useful for other information you might need on FSharp.Core.

P.S. Do take note of the version numbers.  It might be that you, in fact, need to redirect to FSharp.Core version 4.4.0.0 (F# 4.0)

Comment: The F# is a 4.4 so I added FS.Core 4.4 to the C# ones and it said it wanted 4.3.  The redirect did not work.  Chaning the F# project to 4.3 worked well enough.  Thanks